# How to remove empty tags left by <the_date> in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, preg-replace, user-defined-functions, str-replace

Wordpress doesn't support adding styles to the_date the way wp_nav_menu does, so we have to code the style outside the function.

While it's handy that the_date will only show up once each day, it does, however leaves empty tags in the code that would mess up the layout, particularly the marging/padding.

After looking for solutions, the best option is to write a function in the theme's function.php that hooks up with the_content, so this is what I came up with:

```
    function remove_empty_date($string)
    {
    $string = str_replace('/<small class="date">\s*</small>/', '',$string);
    return $string;
    }
    add_filter('the_content','remove_empty_date');
```

The culprit is `<small class="date"></small>`, which manifests in the page as a date-styled field with no date in it.

If there's no better solution than the above, where did the code go wrong so it doesn't remove the unwanted string?

Update: false alarm, Wordpress does support adding tags from the function calls, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date.

Comment: Could you check length of $string, and if its not longer then it would be when its empty just return false?

Comment: I don't get what you mean exactly. Length of string can be matched, but wouldn't it beat the purpose of this function? The aim is to remove the date + wrapping tag, which should have been Wordpress's job really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: add the tag from within the function:

From: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date —

```
<?php the_date( $format, $before, $after, $echo ); ?>
```